# Scroll down to bottom when new message is sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a comment box and I am using following JS to set scroll to bottom and for it scroll down when new message is posted.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('Commentbox');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 500);
```

It kind of works, when a new message is posted it scrolls down, but when I scroll up to look at old messages it scrolls me back down. Is there a way to prevent from that from happening?

Comment: Why are you using interval here? Interval means that your function will run every x mil seconds, in your case, it scrolls every half a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use an interval function to scroll down, cause you scroll every 500 millis with your implementation. I think you have a function, that adds new messages and is called on incoming messages:

```
function addMessage() {
   // here you add the new message to DOM
   // ...

   // then you can scroll down once to show the new messages
   var elem = document.getElementById('Commentbox');
   elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

If you post the code how you add your new messages, i can help you better.

Comment: Thank you sim it worked like a charm all  I to do was add the two lines at the end of send function.

Comment: Great answer however this person asked about the exact problem that im having. Except they didnt post their code. So i have no idea what they mean by "send function." I guess this is what stackoverflow means when they say post as much code as you can. Because then i could reference my code to theirs and possibly solve my problem :(

Comment: The "send function" is in this case the function, which is called, when a new message should be displayed (that could be a http callback or websocket message callback...). I'm sure, that you have such a function (maybe with another name) too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying !

Answer (score 2):

**Because the correct solution was not working for me**, I did something like this:

`$('.your-div-class').scrollTop($('.your-div-class').height()*$('.your-div-class').height());`

**How I came up with the idea?**

1. First I found the height of the div I want to auto-scroll by writing in the console of the browser:

   `console.log($('.your-div-class').height());`.
2. Then I found the scrollTop value:

   `console.log($('.your-div-class').scrollTop());`.
3. Then I put this in the console:

   `$('.your-div-class').scrollTop($('.your-div-class').height()*$('.your-div-class').height());`,

   and found out that it only takes me half way down and realized,

   `$('.your-div-class').scrollTop($('.your-div-class').height()*$('.your-div-class').height());`

   would take me scrolled enough downwards.

**If it doesn't work for you**. You can use: 
`$('.your-div-class').scrollTop($('.your-div-class').height()*1000);`. 
This should work for you just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set the interval as a variable and then clear the interval when the scrolling down is completed, using `window.clearInterval()`.

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('Commentbox');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
  window.clearInterval(timer);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried it out. So with your method, on page refresh box scrolls to the bottom, which is perfect. But When I post a new message I have to manually scroll it down.

Comment: Try using clearInterval after you post the new message and scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

@Wowsk has a good answer, but your follow up question sounds like you are looking for a slight difference in functionality.   I think this should get you there, but I've not tested it yet.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById('Commentbox');

var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
  lastScrollTop = elem.scrollTop
}, 500);

elem.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if(lastScrollTop < elem.scrollTop){
       window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, false);
```

I just went ahead and tested it before posting, hope it helps - refer to the fiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/condorhauck/ak1L12pd/1/

Comment: I can't scroll up anymore ,